# Как выйти из чата на Python Socket?

Tags: python

Я хочу чтобы при введении в Socket чат команду $leave. Он выходил из комнаты и чтоб можно было ещё раз войти. Какая команда есть в модуле Socket для этого?

**Нужна команда и для серверной стороны и для клиентской**

Answer (score 0):

команда закрывает соединение с сервером/клиентом

```
.close()
```